# This Contact PHP form not sending mail

Tags: php, email

Hi I have a simple form to send email. The problem is the PHP is getting executed and echoing success. But I am not receiving any mail. What could be the problem?[image]

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];

$to = 'test@email.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.'  Email: '.$email.'  Phone: '.$phone.'  Subject: '.$subject.'  Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: your@domain.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we     have a valid email address

ini_set('SMTP', 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your request has been recieved. We will be contacting you shortly!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email!";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: if it executed without showing any errors, does not mean that there is no problem. Instead do something like `$status =mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` and then echo the variable `$status` and see what value is it showing.

Comment: ok..did it...its says 1

Comment: ok that means, the function is able to execute. So are you on a hosted server or something like XAMPP on PC ?

Comment: No I am on hosted server..

Comment: hmm...and are you sure that the email ID to which you are sending, i.e. _test@email.com_ is valid?

Comment: echo $subject;check what you get.

Comment: test@email.com is not valid... I want to send it to the mail taken from the form.

Comment: @JMR I get 1 when i do so

Comment: @ tony i am not able to post my answer, can you please check for an alternate way , so that i can post my answer

Comment: not able to paste it in comment

Comment: why is that happening...I think someone marked it as a duplicate question,may be that's why.

Comment: @JMR you can post your answer in this thread... I can read it from there then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122530/discussion-between-jmr-and-tony-stark).